# How to deploy multiple node js apps on one single host and port?

Tags: node.js, web, deployment, web-deployment

I am relatively new to NodeJS and have created three small application each connecting to a different datasource and fetches results. Now I want to deploy all these three application under a single roof i.e a single host and port just like we do on Tomcat/Jetty server - all applications go under webapp folder and simply work. 
**e.g** : *localhost:3000/application1/getEngineData, localhost:3000/application2/getMyToDoList*. 
These are three 2 independent application. The applications count will increase in the future and I don't want to change any server configuration or restart it anytime I deploy an application.

> Thanks in advance for your help folks !

Comment: Why not just increase port number? 3000, 3001, 3002...

Comment: @lcssanches  no.. the whole goal is make the environment feel like an existing tomcat or jetty setup.

Comment: So, I suppose you will have to configure a proxy server for that. What module are you using? Express?

Comment: @lcssanches .. Yes express. Any pointers to configuring a proxy server ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to change any of server configuration, I guess [express-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy) will be an alternative, So you can logically proxy the user (maybe maintaining a list of hosts on path in a database or something like that). Hope that helps